# How do you change the inside color of a radio button in XAML using MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am wishing to change the color of my radio buttons when both selected and deselected, however, methods I have attempted appear to be outdated.

Such as:

```
<RadioButton Content="Add" Background="Blue" Foreground="Green" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" />
```

**Foregound seems to no longer be supported**

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Data="M0,0 L0,6 L6,3 z"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

**Similar issue to the first, `Property="Template"` and `TargetType="RadioButton"`  are no longer supported**

How can you change these colors/states in VS2022 ?
The attached image is the section of the button I am referring to

This image shows the section of the button I am referring to.

[image: Radio button colors]

Comment: you can use the CheckedBackgroundColor property of the RadioButton control

Comment: @HamidMohammadi RadioButton control as in the <style> tags ?

Comment: Just want to point out: Background and BackgroundColor are two completely different things. Gradient drawn with a Brush is Background. Red is BackgroundColor.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a ControlTemplate for your Radiobuttons like that in your ContentPage. Further adjustments like changing the color of the stroke or the inner Ellipse are self-explanatory.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonTemplate">
        <Border
            BackgroundColor="#F3F2F1"
            HeightRequest="20"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Stroke="#F3F2F1"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10"
            StrokeThickness="2"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            WidthRequest="20">
            <Grid WidthRequest="20">
                <Grid
                    
                    HeightRequest="18"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="18">
                    <Ellipse
                        Fill="White"
                        HeightRequest="15"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Stroke="Blue"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        WidthRequest="15" />
                    <Ellipse
                        x:Name="check"
                        Fill="Blue"
                        HeightRequest="8"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        WidthRequest="8" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF3300" />
                                <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#F3F2F1" />
                                <Setter TargetName="check" Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
        <Setter Property="ControlTemplate" Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonTemplate}" />
    </Style>

</ContentPage.Resources>
```